# Get clicked element in delegated event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have some elements that I add to the DOM after the page has been loaded. And I'd like to perform some actions when I click on them. I'm using the delegation with jQuery but I don't know how to get the clicked element when I'm in the fonction ($(this) refers in this case to the parent)

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="hidden"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="hidden"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#parent').click('.child', function(){
    $(this).find('.child').toggleClass("hidden displayed")
});
</script>
```

Let's say I want to toggle the inner div from "hidden" to "displayed" when I click on the "child" div. Currently when I click on the first "child" div, the two "hidden" div will be toggled, and I want to be toggled only the one in the div I clicked.

Comment: Your delegation syntax is wrong. You need to use `.on()`, you can't give a selector as an argument to `.click()`.

Comment: Check out the difference between the event parameters: `event.currentTarget`, `event.delegateTarget`, `event.target`: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.on()` to delegate events. As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) says:

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching `selector`.

So it should be:

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.child', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hidden displayed");
};
```

Your use of `.click('.child', function...)` does not do delegation. It matches the function signature:

```
.click(eventData, handler)
```

described [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler). So it's just binding to the parent, not delegating to the child, that's why you get the wrong value in `this`.

Comment: You're right ! I thought .click and .on('click'...) were equivalent. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: They're only equivalent for binding, not delegating.

Answer (score 17):

Use `e.target` to find out which element the event originated on.

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.child', function(e){
    $(e.target).toggleClass("hidden displayed")
});
```

I also fixed the code a bit - you need to use `.on` for delegated events. (Mentioned by Barmar.)

Comment: It works with .on ! Thanks ! So, it seems that in the case of delegated event .on("click"...) and .click() are not the same at all and with .on(), $(e.target) = $(this)

Comment: +1 This should be the chosen answer. `event.target` actually answers the question in the general case, i.e. when handler context is `.bind ( that )` for example.

Comment: How would you target the '.child' element tho? If you use e.target it returns the element clicked and it could be the child of the '.child'.

Comment: I figured it out. you would use e.currentTarget