# HTML data updating without ajax but not on ajax success jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My code is updating HTML if used without ajax but not in ajax success.

My HTML code

```
<button class="label label-primary likedream" dreamid="12">Like <span class="likecounter">0</span></button>
```

This is my jQuery code file:-

```
jQuery(".likepost").click(function(){

    var likecounter = parseInt(jQuery(this).find(".likecounter").html());

    //jQuery(this).html('Liked '+ '<span class="likecounter">'+(likecounter+1)+'</span>');

    var dreampostId = jQuery(this).attr("dreamid");
     jQuery.post({url: "/hellotest", data: { "dreamId" : dreampostId, "action" : "like"}, success: function(result){
         var updatedres = 'Liked '+ '<span class="likecounter">'+(likecounter+1)+'</span>';
         jQuery(this).html(updatedres);

         jQuery(this).removeClass("likepost");

         }
     });

});
```

if i uncomment my commented line inside code then it updated my html code but don't know why the same code is not working on ajax success. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe its not getting to success? maybe it's firing a failure?

Comment: i am getting success. if i console.log(updatedres) in success then i get my variable data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okk this is how i sorted this out with delegation.

```
jQuery('.dreamaction').on('click', '.likedream', function() {

    var that = this;
    jQuery(that).removeClass("likedream");

    var likecounter = parseInt(jQuery(that).find(".likecounter").html());

    var dreampostId = jQuery(this).attr("dreamid");

    jQuery.post({url: "/dreamaction", data: { "dreamId" : dreampostId, "action" : "like"}, success: function(result){

        var updatedres = 'Liked '+ '<span class="likecounter">'+(likecounter+1)+'</span>';

        jQuery(that).html(updatedres);          

        }
    });
```

});

My HTML code:-

```
<div class="dreamaction">                   
                    <button class="label label-primary likedream" dreamid="12">Like <span class="likecounter">0</span></button>         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are within another function which then replaces the `this` variable. You need to save it in another variable so it doesnt get overridden within the function.

```
jQuery(".likepost").click(function(){

    var likecounter = parseInt(jQuery(this).find(".likecounter").html());

    //jQuery(this).html('Liked '+ '<span class="likecounter">'+(likecounter+1)+'</span>');
    var that = this;
    var dreampostId = jQuery(this).attr("dreamid");
     jQuery.post({url: "/hellotest", data: { "dreamId" : dreampostId, "action" : "like"}, success: function(result){
         var updatedres = 'Liked '+ '<span class="likecounter">'+(likecounter+1)+'</span>';
         jQuery(that).html(updatedres);

         jQuery(that).removeClass("likepost");

         }
     });

});
```

---

Alternativly you can use arrow functions which don't override the this variable.

Comment: wait.. after removing likepost class on success(which is removing).. still its sending an ajax request on click.. Why?

Comment: so please tell me how to remove that event

Comment: Change the event to `jQuery(document).click(".likepost", function () {...})` this attaches the event to the document and that way it will work on all .likepost  that are under document and once you remove the class it will stop working

Comment: No success. it stopped running. now its not picking dreamid attribute

Comment: Read up on this problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657248/576831 seems you need to change to:Change the event to `jQuery(document).on("click",".likepost", function () {...})`  which wont confuse your this

Answer (score 0):

In your success callback `this` is actually the jqXhr object, not the element that was clicked. In a function(the innermost function) `this` is dependant on how the function is called or created and maybe other things.
There are ways to have the `this` in you success callback refer to the item clicked

Setting the context parameter to the item(jQuery.ajax)

```
 jQuery.post({url: "/hellotest", context: this, data: { "dreamId" : dreampostId, "action" : "like"}, success: function(result){
     var updatedres = 'Liked '+ '<span class="likecounter">'+(likecounter+1)+'</span>';
     jQuery(this).html(updatedres);

     jQuery(this).removeClass("likepost");

     }
 });
```

Using arrow functions(es6)

```
 jQuery.post({url: "/hellotest", context: this, data: { "dreamId" : dreampostId, "action" : "like"}, success: result => {
     var updatedres = 'Liked '+ '<span class="likecounter">'+(likecounter+1)+'</span>';
     jQuery(this).html(updatedres);

     jQuery(this).removeClass("likepost");

     }
 });
```

Comment: wait.. after removing likepost class on success(which is removing).. still its sending an ajax request on click.. Why?

Comment: You're looking for event delegation

Comment: i don't know what this event delegation is. i got one other reply and he told me to set my click event like jQuery(document).click(".likepost", function () {...}) but then it can't get my attribute value which i am sending as data on ajax

Comment: I know you don't know what it is, I'm telling you what it is so you can research it

Comment: Hmm. it looks very weird.. i have used ajax many times but dint get this kind of issue